# ASP.NET core command line arguments in the debugger

Tags: asp.net-core

When I debug some asp.net with net 4.7 code, I can specify some arguments in the debugger and the main function is getting them.

I realized that this is not happening with .net core; I can put whatever I want in the "Application arguments" in the debugger tab, the application never sees that data.

Is that yet another case of VS' interface not matching .net core? or did I miss something obvious?

---

Adding more details:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Please confirm `Project Setting` file changes are saved.

In case of `.NET Core` project, it does not save automatically, even if solution compiled.

[image]

Comment: That's what I have; I edited the main post with screenshots

Comment: @Thomas Looks good to me. Did project property save? Is Run configuration set as IIS Express?

Comment: I just found the problem! When I run the code in the debugger, normally the project settings, and any modified source file, is automatically saved prior to compilation. In this case it is not, I have no idea why but the project settings require a manual save!

Comment: @Thomas good for you! wondering why not Project property changes saved automatically on .net core project...

Comment: yes, it's odd; with a regular c# project, or a c++ project, it does save

Comment: It saved the file, restarted VS, and still the problem!

Answer (score 3):

"Project" should be choosen in the "Launch" option.

Answer (score 1):

In my case you need to edit launchSettings.json manually.

[image]

And replace blue color with the project name, save - build, and try to run the project again.
[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution mentioned above did not work for me.

I am able to solve the problem in the following steps.

1. In the project setting, choose the 'project name' in the Profile field instead of "IIS Express".
2. You can find IIS Express icon on the tool bar to launch the application. Switch the label from IIS Express to your project name.